# move shipping field to below shipping methods

Tags: magento2, cart, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, jslayout

I have a block that display in shipping-address-fieldset and i have try to move it using layout but i'm failing. i want it to be displayed below Shipping Methods. please help

Below is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                               <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                               <item name="cms-block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                       <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ShipMethod_CarrierDisplay/cms-block</item>
                                                                   </item>
                                                               </item>
                                                           </item>
                                                       </item>
                                                   </item>
                                               </item>
                                           </item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Below is the method file

```
<?php
namespace ShipMethod\CarrierDisplay\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block;
 
class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
   protected $cmsBlockWidget;
 
   public function __construct(
    Block $block, $blockId)
   {
       $this->cmsBlockWidget = $block;
       $block->setData('block_id', $blockId);
       $block->setTemplate('ShipMethod_CarrierDisplay::default.phtml');
   }
   public function getConfig()
   {
       return [
           'cms_block' => $this->cmsBlockWidget->toHtml()
       ];
   }
}
```

template file

```
<?php
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
?>

<label class="label" style="color:red;">This is a test</label>
```

HTML file

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.cms_block"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the file **`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`** and at the bottom of the file call your custom block

eg.

```
app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

Comment: thank you for response but what i need is to move the layout to be below shipping methods